# R mlr surv.ranger Error in `[.data.frame`(num.response, x == y) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, mlr

Prepare the data ("ovarian" from survival package):

```
require(pacman)
p_load(mlr, survival, tidyverse, ranger)
data("ovarian")
ovarian$rx <- factor(ovarian$rx, 
                     levels = c("1", "2"), 
                     labels = c("A", "B"))
ovarian$resid.ds <- factor(ovarian$resid.ds, 
                           levels = c("1", "2"), 
                           labels = c("no", "yes"))
ovarian$ecog.ps <- factor(ovarian$ecog.ps, 
                          levels = c("1", "2"), 
                          labels = c("good", "bad"))
ovarian <- ovarian %>% mutate(age_group = ifelse(age >=50, "old", "young"))
ovarian$age_group <- factor(ovarian$age_group)
```

Now, run with package 'mlr', surv.ranger:

```
trainTask <- makeSurvTask(data = ovarian, target = c("futime", "fustat"))
trainLearner <- makeLearner("surv.ranger", predict.type = "response")
train(trainLearner,trainTask)
Error in `[.data.frame`(num.response, x == y) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

**Why is there an error? How to fix it?**

Then I tried using another sample dataset ("lung.task" from mlr package), but got another error:

```
trainLearner <- makeLearner("surv.ranger", predict.type = "response")
train(trainLearner,lung.task) # lung.task is from mlr package
Error in ranger::ranger(formula = NULL, dependent.variable.name = tn[1L],  : 
  argument ".weights" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: For me surv.task works fine. Do you have the latest ranger and mlr version?

Your problem with ovarian also appears for me. It has something to do with the factor variables, ovarian2 = ovarian[, c(1,2,3)] works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a long time to find it out, but now I got the error. It comes from the parameter respect.unordered.factors in the package ranger, this also does not work:

```
ranger::ranger(formula = NULL, dependent.variable.name = "futime", status.variable.name = "fustat", data = ovarian, respect.unordered.factors = "order")
```

To solve it for now you can set it to another value:

```
lrn <- makeLearner("surv.ranger", predict.type = "response", respect.unordered.factors = "partition")
lrn <- makeLearner("surv.ranger", predict.type = "response", respect.unordered.factors = "order")
```

Edit: In the newest ranger version from github, this error does not appear anymore. To install it, use the following command and restart R:

```
devtools::install_github("imbs-hl/ranger")
```

See also here: https://github.com/imbs-hl/ranger/issues/359